# Bad practise to catch IllegalStateException? Alternatives?

Tags: null, kotlin, illegalstateexception, convention

I'm building an Android app that processes saved Wi-Fi information. I have a function that returns an ArrayList of WifiEntry objects, but will return null if it can't access the Wi-Fi configuration file (for example, if root access isn't available). At the moment, I'm dealing with it like this:

```
wifiEntries = try {
     WifiEntryLoader().readOreoFile()
} catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
     // Important irelevant stuff
     ArrayList()
}
```

My question is: is there a "better" way to deal with the possibility of a null than by catching an IllegalStateException? I don't want to call my loader function twice. As far as I know, I can't use the Elvis operator to run code, unless I use it with an if expression (ugly and hacky)

Comment: Which function returns `null` and which function throws the exception exactly?

Comment: What does null have to do with IllegalStateException?

Comment: @zsmb13 the `WifiEntryLoader().readOreoFile()` function returns null, and @shmosel assigning null to the `wifiEntries` ArrayList throws the exception.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the elaboration in the comment, it looks like you should just use the Elvis operator and [`emptyList`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/empty-list.html#emptylist):

```
wifiEntries = WifiEntryLoader().readOreoFile() ?: emptyList()
```

Comment: I mentioned why I can't use the Elvis operator in my question.

Comment: I still don't understand why you couldn't - if `readOreoFile` return `null`, you can use the Elvis operator to assign an empty list fo `wifiEntries` instead. 



You said "I can't use the Elvis operator to run code, unless I use it with an if expression (ugly and hacky)", but I don't know what this means.

Comment: I wasn't just assigning an empty list, I was calling some other functions as well. I'm using exceptions now instead of returning null, so it's all good now.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate a bit on zsmb13's answer - Kotlin and Java have two different operators, that are look quite similar.
Java has the ternary conditional operator, which is basically a shorthand notation for an inline if-then-else.

```
// java
Integer test = nullable != null ? nullable : defaultValue;
```

Kotlin's binary 'Elvis operator' allows you to easily define default values. If the left operand is null, the right operand is returned.

```
// kotlin
val nullable: Any? = ...
val defaultValue: Any = ...

val test1: Any = if(nullable != null) nullable else defaultValue
// alternatively
val test2: Any = nullable ?: defaultValue
```

Handling your situation by returning an empty list seems inappropriate, though. You should consider throwing an exception so the calling method can handle this error e.g. by displaying a dialog informing the user that he might be lacking root privileges.

Comment: I don't think anyone calls the Java ternary operator an Elvis operator.

Comment: Actually I have seen that misnomer quite often. Thanks for pointing out, adjusted the answer.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even think of using an exception! I did mention why I can't use the Elvis operator in my question. As the code I'm using is copied from somebody else's app, but not a library, I fixed it easily.